# Programmatically setting Woocommerce product price

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a product (course) that loses value the closer it gets to the end of term.
I've set up 'End date' and 'Weekly price' as custom fields on a page, and can calculate the exact price to pay in PHP.

How do I dynamically create a woocommerce product, or change an established product's price based on the 'Time Left' calculation I performed?

I've tried changing 'price.php' in Woocommerce's template file, but apparently it's just a cosmetic change, and the price reverts to original at basket and checkout.

Haven't the foggiest where else to start, so many thanks in advance.

Comment: try `woocommerce_get_price` filter: eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635553/woocommerce-hook-woocommerce-get-price-how-to-used-in-product-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! This is my solution, and (so far) it works:

```
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {

    $myPrice = 15;

    global $current_user;
    $price = $myPrice;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    return $price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
```

It does target every single product in the store, but as the site only has one product, this works fine.